# Cannot render specific webpage using phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, render

I'm trying to render a webpage, but it doesn't work with some pages. It works with my homepage, and with google, but not with the one shown in the script. How do I work around that?

script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://login.microsoftonline.com', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('micros.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: (1) What's the issue exactly? No file is written or is the image written, but blank? (2) What PhantomJS version do you have? (3) Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your link. These are the error messages I get:
Unable to load resource (#undefinedURL:https://login.microsoftonline.com/)
Error code: 2. Description: Connection closed
Status: fail

Comment: So what PhantomJS version are you using? If it is <1.9.8, then you should try to run it as `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=false script.js`